# How to keep file in memory and read it in other java program

Tags: java

I have one huge data file . reading this file every time in memory is very time consuming. I want to keep this file always in memory ,like a process in background and my other java program can read it from memory on demand.
Can any one tell me how to do that

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "in memory" and "other java program".

Comment: basically everytime my java program executed I dont want to read this large file , I want to keep this file in memory ,so program can read it from there.

Comment: huge data file? How many Gb? Why don't use another process in a client/server relationship using RMI?

Comment: its more than 2 GB file and I am not aware how to do that using RMI and client server relationship

Answer (score 4):

The OS determines which files are kept in memory in its disk cache. If you read the same file repeatedly, it should be in memory unless it is about the size of your memory or more.

If repeated reads are taking a long time, it likely to be the reading/parsing of the file which takes time, not the loading/reading.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is that you import the huge data file into an java object representing the content of the file. In memory this object might need much less memory, or more space, that depends.

Once you have that object, you dont need to import it anymore.

The first time you need that object, you read the file.
Later when you need that data again, you access your object but read not the file anymore.